# Convert string containing bits to vector<bool>

Tags: c++

I have a `std::string` of bits like `01001110`. How to make it `std::vector<bool>`?

Comment: Loop through the string, compare the element to `'1'`, and add the boolean result to your vector. This is a trivial loop, please show a little effort.

Comment: Just be aware that `std::vector<bool>` is [not a real container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
std::string bits("10101011110");
std::vector<bool> myVec;
myVec.reserve(bits.size());
for(auto a : bits)
    myVec.push_back(a == '1');
```