# How to read dictionary file to a map<char, vector<bool> >?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I have a text file which is a dictionary of pair "character-binary code". I need to read that dictionary from the file and put the values to map<char, vector > to perform some other operations on it.
I decided to read each line separately first(because binary codes are variable length) and then I need to assign each character to first member of the map(char) and the binary code to a second part(vector of bools)

My dictionary file:

```
'0111010
,110110
.11110101
:110101011
;111101000
A0011010
B01110011
I0011011
S01110110
T0111000
W01110111
Y111101001
a0000
b1111011
```

My code:

```
    vector<bool> CharCode;
    char key;
    char code;
    string str;
    map<char, vector<bool> > dict;//associative array of charater and its binary code

    ifstream Dictionary(Dict);

    while (getline(Dictionary, str)) 
    {
        std::cout << str << "\n";
        //But how to put the key and code to char and vector<bool> respectively?

    }

    Dictionary.close();
```

Comment: You can use `map[key] = value` assignments to fill the map.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt but the value is not a simple variable, it is a vector. I think I won't work

Comment: @brc-dd Thank you very much! Now I understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this much code will suffice:

```cpp
// include necessary files
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy
#include <fstream>   // for std::ifstream
#include <iostream>  // for std::cout
#include <iterator>  // for std::ostream_iterator
#include <map>       // for std::map
#include <string>    // for std::string
#include <vector>    // for std::vector

// function to convert string containing 0s and 1s
// to std::vector<bool> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27367542
auto str_to_vec(std::string &&s) {

  // declare vector to return, and later insert into dictionary
  std::vector<bool> v;

  // extract characters from the string repeatedly
  // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for
  for (auto ch : s)

    // push true in vector if character is '1' else false, I've
    // ignored checking if the string contains only 0s and 1s,
    // you may wish to add a validation check for that yourself
    v.push_back(ch == '1');

  // return the constructed vector
  return v;
}

// driver function
int main() {

  // open your file, replace filename with your dictionary file
  std::ifstream fin("my_dict.txt");

  // declare your dictionary
  std::map<char, std::vector<bool>> dict;

  // extract strings from the file repeatedly
  for (std::string str; fin >> str;)

    // check if length of string is atleast 2 you may skip this
    // if already guaranteed
    if (str.length() > 1)

      // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at
      dict[str[0]] = str_to_vec(str.substr(1));

  // now do something with your dictionary here
  for (auto &&[ch, v] : dict) {
    std::cout << '\n' << ch << " : ";
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<bool>(std::cout, ""));
  }
}
```

Sample run : https://wandbox.org/permlink/1fi756kz8grmNPf6